# Core Animation: Pause before autoreversing?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I have an animation that animates a layer along a curved path and then back. I would like the layer to pause before the auto-reversing kicks in. Is there an easy way to do this with Core Animation?

Here is the code I'm using to start the animation.

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.duration = animationDuration;
animation.path = curvedPath;
animation.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto;
animation.delegate = nil;
animation.autoreverses = YES;
[self.myView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"cardAnimation"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of to pause in an auto-reversing animation is to start a timer for 1/2 the animation time.

When the timer fires, set the speed of your animation to 0, and launch another timer. When the second timer fires, set the speed of your animation back to 1 (or whatever it was before) again. That should look good if you're using ease-in, ease-out animation timing, since the animation slows to a stop before reversing.

Failing that, you'd probably have to create separate forward and reverse animations, set a delegate for the animation, and in the completion method, pause and then start the reverse animation.